# Url routing in asp .net web form using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Current URL

```
http://localhost:64632/used/search.aspx#city=176&make=49&model=49.242&fuel=1
```

Make URL

```
http://localhost:64632/used-cars/used-petrol-audi-sedan-cars-in-bangalore
```

it's possible?

> Note

```
All value are accept the query string in page load how it's work
```

Comment: Close to being a duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page